# python 3. Use variable from one method in another method within the same class

Tags: json, python-3.x, class, methods

I'm trying to build a class with two methods: first method to check if the file was downloaded without errors and the second method to save the downloaded file. This code works as I want it to but it downloads the file twice. I want to use the `r` variable from the first method in the second method without downloading the file again.

The function to send email works just fine.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import requests

class checkGet_and_loads:
    # check if the get is successfull or not
    def get(self, url, file):
        # download the file    
        self.r = requests.get(url)

        # check if file was downloaded with no errors
        if self.r.status_code != 200:
            # send email to gmail
            # emailBody = 'Sending email. Error with downloading the ' + file + ' file.'
            # send_email( fromaddr = emailFrom, pwd = password, toaddr = emailTo, Subject = emailSubject, body = emailBody )
            print( 'Error: Unexpected response {}'.format(self.r) )

        else:
            print( ' Not sending email. No errors found when downloading the ' + file + ' file.' )

    # loads the json file
    def loads(self, url, file):
        # download the file
        self.r = requests.get(url)

        # loads the json file
        self.to_loads = json.loads( self.r.text, object_pairs_hook = OrderedDict )
        return( self.to_loads )

# Check if test file is downloaded without errors. If errors found while downloading then send email; otherwise, don't email
# link for test file
url = 'http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format=json'
file = 'test'

checkGet_and_loads().get(url, file)

test_json = checkGet_and_loads().loads(url, file)
```

So the second method should look like this:

```
    # loads the json file
    def loads(self):
        # loads the json file
        to_loads = json.loads( self.r.text, object_pairs_hook = OrderedDict )
        return(to_loads)
```

But, I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'checkGet_and_loads' object has no attribute 'r'

I tried all solutions on SO and other sites and didn't figure it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are creating a temporary object and then creating a new object:

```
checkGet_and_loads().get(url, file)
test_json = checkGet_and_loads().loads(url, file)
```

It should be this:

```
data_source = checkGet_and_loads()
data_source.get(url, file)
test_json = data_source.loads()
```

Then you won't need to call `requests.get` in the `.loads` function.

Comment: it works. Thanks.  
a little edit: it should be `test_json = data_source.loads()` instead of `test_json = data_source.loads(url, file)`

Comment: @nick Sure. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need can be achieved much simpler. If you have a class where there's only two methods and one of them `__init__`, it should be a [function](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0). In you case you don't even have init.

```
def load_file(url, filename):
    response = r.get(url)
    if response.status == 200:
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            json.dump(f, response.json(object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict))
```

you can `raise CustomException()` if `status` isn't `200` and then catch it and log errors.

I also suggest to read python code style (PEP8)